# References an external font css file with eBay Ad

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've have read up many other answers but just can't see what I'm doing wrong, I have a set of custom fonts created using iconmoon, I've downloaded the css and font files and uploaded to a directory on my website, I'm trying to reference font.css file via an Ad I've put together in eBay, but I can never get it to work, if I reference Iconmoons development font.css file then I can see my Icons, any ideas would be great

//This works

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://i.icomoon.io/public/53e1b82fac/DMQDartsFonts/style.css">
```

//This does not work

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.my-site.com/fonts.css">
```

Comment: `https` most likely the reason.....

Comment: hmm, I've tried <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.my-site.com/fonts.css"> with https:// in the url and uploaded to https folder , still the same though

Comment: Ok, so my site is not SSL certified yet, could that be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your style sheet. If that's not gonna work, it means that your URL cannot be read or you put the wrong path in the link..

```
@import url("http://www.my-site.com/fonts.css");
```